# Limits of $f$ in this formula

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

By integration by parts: $$\int u dv=uv-\int vdu$$ Now I used this to create a clever little formula: $$\int f(x)dx=-\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}f^{(k-1)}(x)$$ I did this by setting $u=f(x)$ and $v=1$: $$\int f(x)dx=xf(x)-\int xf'(x)dx$$Then we set $u=f'(x)$ and $v=x$: $$\int f(x)dx=xf(x)-\int xf'(x)dx=xf(x)-\frac{x^2}{2}f'(x)+\int\frac{x^2}{2}f''(x)dx$$And so on. Now I decided to test this formula. It worked for $f(x)=x$ but not $f(x)=x^{-1}$. What are the limitations for $f$? I found two: It's derivative must be continuous and the sum above must converge $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Are there any others?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @ConMan Yes I didn't think of that, tysm! This is the Maclaurin series.